# Is this a wandering spider?

Tags: species-identification

I recently visited the Peruvian Amazon near Puerto Maldono and found this spider. Can someone please help me in identifying it? It was about 7cm in length, including legs.

I hope that it might be a wandering spider, but idk maybe it could be a massive wolf spider or some other spider…?

I poked its leg gently with a long piece of grass and it didn’t flee, but raised it’s front two legs (only slighly though) as I’ve seen wandering spiders do in videos, and I’ve never seen wolf spiders do this?

Idk if this helps, but anyways, would love some help!

[image]

Comment: Nice! It's not a wolf spider; the eyes are wrong for that. I think it is; the single dark line on the dorsal carapace and the striped palps certainly suggest *Phoneutria*, but I'm not sure, so this is a comment, not an answer. It may not have felt threatened enough to go full-on upright. I hope someone else knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

[image]

Ctenidae, number 7 on this graphic, have a distinct eye pattern from the wolf spiders (lycosidae; number 1).

I couldn't tell you the species, though.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Just in case you're curious, the largest wolf spider that you'd likely find in Peru is probably *Lycosa erythrognatha*, which doesn't get much more than 4-5ish centimeters across.